# Union All with Two Keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I have two tables ('Field' and 'Wides') with the exact same columns ('HorseID' and 'RaceID') and I want to merge the tables on these columns, whilst also merging the data from both tables. My code at the moment only merges the two columns.

```
select field2.horseid, field2.raceid
from field2
union all
select wides2.horseid, wides2.raceid
from wides2
```

Comment: Please include the full table structure for both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want a join between the two tables?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM field2 t1
INNER JOIN wides2 t2
    ON t2.horseid = t1.horseid AND
       t2.raceid = t1.raceid;
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I make this table into a new one or should I update an existing table. Whichever is easier.

Comment: You could use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, where the select is my answer.  But, I can't give you an exact query because I don't know the full table structure of both tables.

Comment: Also I noticed that the tables have merged based on the columns, but there are still duplicate columns for 'HorseID' and 'RaceID'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DISTINCT` keyword in with select to get the unique result set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.horseid,t1.raceid....<col name> FROM <table>
```